# Can mongoose get me all different values for a certain field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, distinct

I have a mongo database that stores the rooms in a hotel. There are different types of rooms (singles, doubles, etc.). I want the user to be able to define his own room type. Is it possible to get a list entries from mongoose that contains exactly one of each room type, similar to an SQL DISTINCT query?

I would rather avoid storing different room types in a separate model, since this would add additional complexity.

I'm using ES6, so if that simplifies it, go ahead.

Comment: I took me some time to find the 'distinct' keyword, thats why I didn't find other questions for this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe Mongoose also has its own version of [distinct with a model object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.distinct) or [distinct with a query object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct)

For your example, seems like you could do either, so you can do either:

```
Model.distinct('room_type', function(err, room_types) {
    //do something with room_types
});
```

or

```
Model.find({}).distinct('room_type', function(err, room_types) {
    //do something with room_types
});
```

respectively.

Comment: Ah, I just found the online documentation. I had no idea how powerful mongoose actually is. This is exactly what I'm looking for...

Comment: I tried your method but this is what i get as a result Cast to ObjectId failed for value "categories" at path "_id" for model "MCQ"

Comment: Bro am sorry that was my mistake i made some error in API your code works perfectly thank you for this